# How to resolve Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'getParameters failed (empty parameters)' in C# xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a function called Scanner

```
  private async void Scanner()
    {
       try
            {
                var scannerPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
                scannerPage.Title = "Scanner";
                scannerPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                {
                    scannerPage.IsScanning = false;

                    string resultado = Convert.ToString(result);

                    if (resultado.Contains("http") || resultado.Contains("https"))
                    {
                        Browser.OpenAsync(resultado, BrowserLaunchMode.External);
                            Navigation.PopAsync();
                        }
                        else
                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                            {
                                Navigation.PopAsync();
                                subs = result.Text.Split('\t');
                                string cadena = "var1N°: " + subs[0] + "\var2N°: " + subs[1] + "\var3N°: " + subs[2];
                                await this.DisplayAlert("Data QR", cadena, "OK");
                                sacarFotos();
                            });
                    };
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(scannerPage);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Sorry we had a problem, "OK");
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
            }
            
    }
```

It works perfectly when I use it. But if I execute it here:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I have the error "Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'getParameters failed (empty parameters)'"

How could I resolve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jason I am sorry. I did it. The problems happens when the code entry into the Scanner(); when I use the function it gives the error that I mentioned before.

Comment: Which specific line causes the exception?  Have you stepped through it in the debugger or examined the stack trace?  When you say it "works perfectly" you are not giving us any context about how it is being called.

Comment: @Jason I'll explain myself better. When I run the app and for example, I declare Scanner() in the constructor and I don't use **protected override void OnAppearing()** it works perfectly but what I need is execute the Scanner every time that the Page is called. So, that's why I need the function **protected override void OnAppearing()** but if I execute the scanner there it doesn't work and gives me the error. for some reason in debug mode the scanner runs 2 times before I use the function and then throws me the error. Am I clear?

Comment: if it is running twice it might be as simple as adding a check to prevent that